# Как получить доступ к каждому элементу html в js

Tags: javascript, html

1. Создайте простую HTML-страницу, состоящую из 15-20 элементов (html, head, body, p, ul, ol, li, div, h1, h2 и так далее), делая так же и вложенные друг в друга элемента (например, h2 и div внутри другого div).
2. Получите доступ к каждому элементу (за исключением пробельных символов), выведя его в консоль.

про querySelectorAll я знаю
имею ввиду можно ли как то с циклами провернуть?
всем прописать const и console?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Хмм. Может вам следует к каждому элементу задать айди, затем в js создать массив с этими айди и провести его через цикл и в цикле обратиться к каждому айди с помощью getElementById()  и выводить всё на консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Пробежаться по всем тегам - использовать `*` в `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    console.log(node.nodeName)
});
```

---

Можно некоторые исключить

```js
let tagExclude = ['style', 'script'];

document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    if (!tagExclude.includes(node.nodeName.toLowerCase()))
        console.log(node.nodeName)
});
```

Естесственно можно использовать `filter` для фильтрации.